# How can we get many elements using one single javascript function?

Tags: javascript, class, toggle

[i want this function to work on every element but it affects only one item. How can i use a single function to change class for each element when mousing over the elements. I have seen videos where we can use container div to get this div instead of getting single child. can you help me?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qc70H.jpg)

Comment: Please include the code directly in your question, do not include an image of it.

Answer (score 0):

Each time that the **onmouseover** event is dispatched, an event object is made available for you to work with. This **event** object includes (between many other things), the exact HTML element for which this event has been dispatched.

Simply make the following change to your custom method to make use of this mechanism:

```js
<div class="item" onmouseover={cambiar}></div>


function cambiar(event) {
var cambio = event.target;

cambio.classList.toggle('item2');
}
```